# Cannot read property 'duration' of null with wavesurfer

Tags: svelte, wavesurfer.js

I load 9 wavesurferobject in a modal with svelte. closing the modal destroys all wavesurferobject. reopening the modal all wavesurferobjecst have a ready event true, but play causes:

```
Cannot read property 'duration' of null wavesurfer.js:2134
```

Have no clue, why duration now is needed or missing.

Answer (score 0):

I switched back from backend: 'MediaElement' to webaudio and the error is gone. Have no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Found it. Was not originaly a WaveSurfer issue. There was still a current mediaelement defined which was hard to debug.